# Wicket FileUpload for large files effectively by slicing the file and uploading asynchronously

Tags: file-upload, asynchronous, wicket

Hi I am working on large file upload component. I am looking for efficient way of uploading large files. I googled and found few does by slicing the large files and uploading asynchronously. I am looking for the similar implementation in Wicket. Is there any similar way in Wicket to achieve the same?

Comment: Slicing up the file happens client-side and most of the wicket stuff happens server side. You're going to have to do some javascript magic to pull this of. As far as I know there is no standard wicket component that does this for you.

Comment: Found something in javascript in below link, trying to integrate with wicket. https://code.google.com/p/java-large-file-uploader/

Answer (score 1):

You could look into integrating Wicket with [jQuery FileUpload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) which supports asynchronous and [chunked uploads](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Chunked-file-uploads).

There is a [tutorial](http://wicketinaction.com/2012/11/uploading-files-to-wicket-iresource/) and a working example on [GitHub](https://github.com/martin-g/blogs/tree/master/file-upload). I have used this solution for multi-file upload in two projects and it works great.